# How to have sequence number field for a parent in Google Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I have a entity in Datastore that looks something like this:

```
public class UserEntry {
    @Parent
    private Ref<User> parent;
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String seqNumber;
    private String name;
}
```

I am trying to maintain a sequence number for each user. i.e first entry for user should have seqNumber as 1 the next as 2 and so on. What is the best way to achieve this?

i.e:
1) how can i get the seqNumber for the last entry for a user

2) How do i ensure while writing that another process has not written an entry for the user with the same seqNumber. I cannot make seqNumber the id for the entry.

Comment: Why do you need that? Why don't you use default generated id?

Comment: I have a business need to generate the numbers in sequence

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid that the only way to achieve this is to use datastore's support for transactions. Note, however, that this solution comes with a considerable contention risk. And with a risk of skipping some values in the sequence when done incorrectly. Let me start with a naive approach to illustrate the basic idea.

**A straight forward solution (NAIVE APPROACH):**

You could create a dedicated entity, let's call it `Sequence`, which would have a single property, let's call it `value`. At the beginning, the `value` property would contain `0` (or `1`, depending where you want the sequence to start). Then, prior to creating any new `UserEntry` you would have to execute a transaction which would:

1. obtain the current `value`,
2. increment `value` by one (within the same transaction).

The fact that you would be using transactions would prevent concurrent requests from obtaining the same sequential id. Note, however, that there would have to be exactly one "instance" of the `Sequence` entity kind stored in the datastore. Updating this entity too rapidly could lead to contention issues. Also, this approach uses non-idempotent transactions which could lead to skipping some values from the sequence.

**Contention risk:**

Beware that the straight forward solution described above would limit throughput of your application. Your application wouldn't be able to handle creating more than one `UserEntry` per second for an extended period of time. This is because creating a `UserEntry` would require updating the `Sequence` entity. And "one write per second" is an approximate limit for writing into a single entity, see https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits

**Danger of non-idempotent transactions:**

Datastore can occasionally throw an error claiming that a transaction failed even though it did not, see https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions If you would retry the transaction after such "non-error", you would end up executing the transaction twice. In your scenario, you would end up incrementing `value` twice for creation of a single `UserEntry`, thus skipping one value from the sequence (or more if you would be extremely unlucky and got the "non-error" several times in a row).

This is why Google suggests to make your transactions idempotent, meaning that executing the transaction a thousand times should have the same effect on the resulting state of the underlying data as executing it once. A good example of an idempotent transaction is renaming a user. If you tell someone to be renamed to "Carl" a thousand times, he will end up being called... well, "Carl". If, on the other hand, you tell our `value` counter to be incremented a thousand times... You get the picture.

**Better solutions:**

If you are ok with the above mentioned risks of the straight forward solution, you are ok to go. But here are some tips how to avoid these issues:

*Avoiding contention:*

You could use a task queue to postpone the assignment of `seqNumber`. By making sure that the queue won't send requests more than once per second, you would easily avoid possible contention issues. Obvious downside of this solution is that there would be some delay before the `seqNumber` property would be assigned to the newly created `UserEntry`. I don't know if this is acceptable for you.

*Design transactions to be idempotent:*

Here is a simple modification which would make the transactions idempotent: Instead of using the `value` property to hold the actual counter value, use it to store `id` of the lastly created `UserEntry`. Then, when deciding what the `seqNumber` for the next `UserEntry` should be, retrieve the lastly added `UserEntry`, use its `seqNumber` to calculate the next value, and than update the `Sequence` entity (as many times as you want) telling it, your `value` property is now equal to "some particular id".

**Final note:**

You are very correct in NOT using the `seqNumber` as id of the entity. Using monotonically increasing values as entity ids is another well known contention trap, see https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices

Hope this helps.